# I need to get a list of values in nested objects in javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, nested

Here is my object :

```
let regions = new Object();
  regions = {
    st0 : {
      svgId : ".st0",
      htmlId : "#olmes",
      gradientId : "st0-gradient"
    },
    st1 : {
      svgId : ".st1",
      htmlId : "#foix",
      gradientId : "st1-gradient"
    },
    st2 : {
      svgId : ".st2",
      htmlId : "#tarascon",
      gradientId : "st2-gradient"
    },
    st3 : {
      svgId : ".st3",
      htmlId : "#haute-ariege",
      gradientId : "st3-gradient"
    },
    st4 : {
      svgId : ".st4",
      htmlId : "#mirepoix",
      gradientId : "st4-gradient"
    },
    st5 : {
      svgId : ".st5",
      htmlId : "#portes-ariege",
      gradientId : "st5-gradient"
    },
    st6 : {
      svgId : ".st6",
      htmlId : "#arize-leze",
      gradientId : "st6-gradient"
    },
    st7 : {
      svgId : ".st7",
      htmlId : "#couserans",
      gradientId : "st7-gradient"
    }
  };
```

Here is my jQuery code I creadted to interact with an SVG map

```
  jQuery.each(regions, function(ids, cssId){
    jQuery(cssId.svgId).addClass("region")
      jQuery(cssId.svgId).click(function() {
        jQuery(".region-titre").removeClass("region-active");
        jQuery(cssId.htmlId).addClass("region-active");
        jQuery(".region").removeClass("st0-gradient st1-gradient st2-gradient st3-gradient st4-gradient st5-gradient st6-gradient st7-gradient");
        jQuery(cssId.svgId).addClass(cssId.gradientId);
     });
  });
```

I'm looking to find a way to get a list of ALL gradientId in a list to integrate it more properly into my jQuery code.

Thx for help, im still learning and I cant find it by my own.

Sorry if question have been already asked.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can use `Object.values` to retrieve an array containing all the objects, then `map()` to build the array containing only the `gradientId` values:

```
var gradients = Object.values(regions).map(o => o.gradientId);
```

```js
let regions = {
  st0: {
    svgId: ".st0",
    htmlId: "#olmes",
    gradientId: "st0-gradient"
  },
  st1: {
    svgId: ".st1",
    htmlId: "#foix",
    gradientId: "st1-gradient"
  },
  st2: {
    svgId: ".st2",
    htmlId: "#tarascon",
    gradientId: "st2-gradient"
  },
  st3: {
    svgId: ".st3",
    htmlId: "#haute-ariege",
    gradientId: "st3-gradient"
  },
  st4: {
    svgId: ".st4",
    htmlId: "#mirepoix",
    gradientId: "st4-gradient"
  },
  st5: {
    svgId: ".st5",
    htmlId: "#portes-ariege",
    gradientId: "st5-gradient"
  },
  st6: {
    svgId: ".st6",
    htmlId: "#arize-leze",
    gradientId: "st6-gradient"
  },
  st7: {
    svgId: ".st7",
    htmlId: "#couserans",
    gradientId: "st7-gradient"
  }
};

var gradients = Object.values(regions).map(o => o.gradientId);
console.log(gradients);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

One thing to note is that `Object.values` is not available natively in IE. A [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values#Polyfill) is available though.

Comment: Thank you Rory for the response

Answer (score 0):

you can get the keys of the object regions using Object.keys. Then iterate through the keys through map function generate the list as you required.

```
let regions = new Object();
  regions = {
    st0 : {
      svgId : ".st0",
      htmlId : "#olmes",
      gradientId : "st0-gradient"
    },
    st1 : {
      svgId : ".st1",
      htmlId : "#foix",
      gradientId : "st1-gradient"
    },
    st2 : {
      svgId : ".st2",
      htmlId : "#tarascon",
      gradientId : "st2-gradient"
    },
    st3 : {
      svgId : ".st3",
      htmlId : "#haute-ariege",
      gradientId : "st3-gradient"
    },
    st4 : {
      svgId : ".st4",
      htmlId : "#mirepoix",
      gradientId : "st4-gradient"
    },
    st5 : {
      svgId : ".st5",
      htmlId : "#portes-ariege",
      gradientId : "st5-gradient"
    },
    st6 : {
      svgId : ".st6",
      htmlId : "#arize-leze",
      gradientId : "st6-gradient"
    },
    st7 : {
      svgId : ".st7",
      htmlId : "#couserans",
      gradientId : "st7-gradient"
    }
  };

Object.keys(regions).map(key => regions[key].gradientId)
```

Output

```
["st0-gradient", "st1-gradient", "st2-gradient", "st3-gradient", "st4-gradient", "st5-gradient", "st6-gradient", "st7-gradient"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The first lines of your script are unnecessary. On line one you are constructing a new empty object and assigning that to your `regions` variable. Then on the next line you are reassigning the value of that variable to another object you create. `{key: val, ...}` is a way of constructing objects in javascript, and you can just write

```js
let regions = {
 st0 : {
      svgId : ".st0",
      htmlId : "#olmes",
      gradientId : "st0-gradient"
    },
//...
};
```

The answer Rory McCrossan gave is correct (https://stackoverflow.com/a/61248366/342918), but I'd argue that you can rewrite your logic in a way that is easier to maintain. Most of your values you are using seem to be constructable from the order they have in your list, so I would suggest that you just create a list of regions and update your jQuery a bit as I show below. This would mean that you don't have to repeat yourself in so many places with all the risks of making a mistake somewhere.

```js
let regions = [
    "#olmes",
    "#foix",
    "#tarascon",
    "#haute-ariege",
    "#mirepoix",
    "#portes-ariege",
    "#arize-leze",
    "#couserans",
];

function makeGradientId(id){ return ".st" + id + "-gradient" };
function makeSvgId(id){ return ".st" + id };
// in javascript, an array can be regarded as a fancy object with the keys '0', '1', '2', '3',...
const allGradientIds = Object.keys(regions).map(makeGradientId);

jQuery.each(function(index, htmlId) {
    const svgId = makeSvgId(index);
    const gradientId = allGradientIds[index];

    jQuery(svgId).addClass("region");
    jQuery(svgId).click(function() {
        jQuery(".region-titre").removeClass("region-active");
        jQuery(htmlId).addClass("region-active");
        jQuery(".region").removeClass(allGradientIds.join(" "));
        jQuery(svgId).addClass(gradientId);
    });
});
```

In more modern javascript we would write the helper functions above as:

```js
const makeGradientId = (id) => `.st${id}-gradient`;
const makeSvgId = (id) => `.st${id}`;
```

which is easier to read in my opinion, but may take some practice getting used to. (see https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-arrow-functions/ and https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-template-strings-2/)

Comment: thx a lot ill take a look to your option for knowledge ! Take care